# viewpushcontroller animation off does not load page correctly

Tags: xcode

in my current code, with viewpushcontroller animation on it loads the next page as intended (next page loads with activityindicator during download), however when I turn animation off, the current page hangs while downloading occurs in background and then next page loads only after download occurs.  Is there a way I can have no animation and load the next page immediately?

current page:

```
AudioVC*vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AudioVC"];
    vc.mediObj = _mediObj;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

next page:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    flagCellWillAppear=0;
    detailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [detailArray removeAllObjects];
    [detailArray addObjectsFromArray:[_mediObj.steps mutableCopy]];
    _titleLbl.text = _mediObj.title;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    _backBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    _playView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    _mainContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

thank you.